# Why simple Angular hello world is not working?

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I have been trying to do some proof of concept and I was expecting Plunker to write `4` for the expression `{{40/10}}` but it never did. What's wrong with it? However I see Scott Allen was able to do so.
Here is my plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/OTuxWEMmlWObMgGy9o2Z?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0"
    src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{40/10}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the link to the Scott Allen example you're referring to?

Comment: It here in this tutorial: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angularjs-get-started&author=scott-allen&name=angularjs-get-started-m1-introduction&clip=2&mode=live

Comment: There's something wrong with your script src URL, I tried your example with an older Angular version and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks Chara, could you post that Url here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the script you import is Angular 2. If you import Angular 1.x.x, your example will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 40/10 }}
  </body>

</html>
```

If you want to learn how to use Angular 2, look at their [website](https://angular.io/).

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to angular2 while using an angular1 directive ng-app.

Here is a link to a working plnkr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/knhRA1WWyHUVr9Gd1cdV?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 40/10 }}
  </body>

</html>
```

Angular 2 is a complete redesign from angular1, so a code working in Angular 1 will not work in Angular 2.